# What is the correct nodejs architecure for database connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I am generally connecting to a database before listening a port like this:

```js
//server.js
MongoClient.connect(process.env.mongo_url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {
  if(err) throw err
  console.log('db connected')

  global.db = client.db(database_name);

  app.listen(process.env.port || 3000, ()=>{
      console.log(`Server listening on http://localhost:${process.env.port || 3000}`)
  })
});
```

And using it through the connection from the global variable. Lately, I started to add service layers in order to use the same service from several other places. I also integrated [make-runnable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-runnable) lib to my services so that I can execute service functions from the terminal. Ex. `node usersService.js register <email> <password>` for below service.

```js
// usersService.js
exports.register = (email, password)=>{
  // business logic to register the user
}

require('make-runnable');
```

```js
// usersController.js
import usersService = require('./services/usersService')
router.post('/register',async (req, res)=>{
  usersService.register(req.body.email, req.body.password)
  ...
})
```

Since the service needs a db connection, I created a db module and edited the service:

```js
// db.js
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb')

function connect(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        console.log(`Trying to connect to ${process.env.mongo_url}`)
        MongoClient.connect(process.env.mongo_url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {
            if(err) return reject(err)
            console.log('db connected')
            resolve(client.db(database_name))
        });
    })
}

exports.connect = connect
```

```js
// usersService.js
exports.register = (email, password)=>{
  // connect to db if executed from terminal
  if (require.main === module) 
      var db = await require('../../db.js').connect()
  }
  // business logic to register the user
}

require('make-runnable');
```

This structure works. But code snippet that I added to service for db connection in case of executing from terminal seems unpleasant. I need to add it to all service functions. How can I structure the project so that I can call each service function from the terminal that requires a db connection? Any architectural suggestions are welcome.